# What are these lighted shapes on Google Maps?

Tags: satellite-oddities

I was surfing on Google Maps satellite mode and I found these odd objects in northern Bolivia[image: odd]. They look like turned-on TVs, but the largest of them has a length of about 48 yards!

Can anyone identify these? Maybe they are mirrors?

The coordinates: -10.297946, -66.350233

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shiny objects are the metal roofs of buildings. The photos have been taken at a time when the roofs reflect much of the sunlight towards the camera.